# .NET CE 2.0 Data Access NullReferenceException when assigning DB fields to List(of T)

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, windows-ce, compact-framework2.0

The code below grabs data based on a provided username and password in VS 2008. When I Check the `reader.FieldCount` it contains all of the fields it should contain. The issue I am having is at `results.Add`, which is defined at the top of the file as `Dim results As List(Of String)`. When the program reaches that line, a NullReferenceException is thrown, though I have no idea why.

The program is meant to run on an MC9190-G and works up to that point in the code on the device. I am not using an emulator. the code is deployed directly to the device for testing.

```
    Public Function getUser(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String)
    Dim ecif As New EncryptionInfo
    Dim ec As New Encryption(ecif.key, ecif.iv)
    Dim pass_dec, temp As String
    Dim i As Integer
    connect()
    query = "SELECT * FROM UserInfo WHERE Username = '" + username.ToString + "'"
    comm = New SqlCommand(query, cn)
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader

    If (reader.FieldCount <> 0) Then
        i = 0
        reader.Read()
        While (i < reader.FieldCount)
            If (i = 1) Then
                pass_dec = reader.GetString(i)
                results.Add = ec.Decrypt(pass_dec)
                Continue While
                i += 1
            End If
            temp = reader.Item(i).ToString
            results.Add(temp)
            i += 1
        End While
        reader.Close()
        cn.Close()
        comm.Dispose()
        Return results
    End If


    MessageBox.Show("No results")
    Return Nothing



    End Function
```

Comment: `results.Add = ec.Decrypt(pass_dec)` <-- Does this even compile? Also, read up on the [**`New` keyword**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77s47661.aspx).

Comment: Everything compiles perfectly. Am I missing a new keyword somewhere? I thought I declared everything properly.

Comment: That line still troubles me, because it shouldn't. Anyway, yes you are missing a `New` keyword somewhere; in the declaration of your list: `Dim results As New List(Of String)`. Inspecting the list with the debugger once the error was thrown would've showed you that it is null.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. I don't usually use VB and this one caught me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the keyword `New`:

```vb
Dim results As New List(Of String)
```